# How to tell ActiveRecord that a particular column belongs to a certain class and to fetch the associated class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a class called Conversation and a column called "assigned_to" that stores the User.id.

I would like to load all the Conversations, but also load the associated Users, how can I do this?

My Conversation class is:

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :name, :assigned_to
end
```

So I need to add `has_one :user`, but how to link to the `:assigned_to` field?  I am currently populating the assigned_to field in the controller, but now I'm trying to show the list with user information and curious how to do this.

Seems like basic ActiveRecord functionality, but I'm relatively new to it and the documentation doesn't seem to have an example where the column is renamed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that should something like :

```
belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :assigned_to
```

If you want more informations about available options, you can look at the [API](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_one)

Comment: Thanks ByScripts, so if I'm looping through the conversations, how can I access that class then?  Ie. <%= conversation.?? %>

Comment: But what if I had another attribute on the class, for example, last_updated_by, how can I distinguish?  If I reference conversation.user, how will ActiveRecord know if I mean :assigned_to user, or :last_updated_by user?

Comment: Then you could add `has_one :last_updater, class_name: "User", foreign_key: :last_updated_by` and access it with `conversation.last_updater`

Comment: Sweet, thanks ByScripts, that's exactly what I was looking for.  I just need to get used to the different conventions, seems there are a lot of them and need to get used to using them more.

Comment: FYI, just tried it out, had to change has_one to belongs_to to make it work.